# How to set font size using TextItem.setText() in PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, text, plot, formatting, pyqtgraph

When creating a TextItem to be added to a plotItem in PyQtGraph, I know it is possible to format the text using html code, however I was wondering how to format the text (i.e. change font size) when updating the text through TextItem.setText()? or do I need to destroy/re-create a TextItem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not documented, but the method you want is `TextItem.setHtml()`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `TextItem.setFont()` to change the font size:

```py
from PySide2.QtGui import QFont

font = QFont()
font.setPixelSize(9)

textDie = TextItem('Your string', anchor=(0.5, 0.5))
ui.outPlot.addItem(textDie) # ui.outPlot is the pyqtgraph object in my GUI.
textDie.setPos(x,y)
textDie.setFont(font)
```